Get cost price on frontend
I’m trying to get the cost price attribute from the advanced pricing section to show on frontend. I’ve set the attribute to be visible on frontend but not sure on the code I need to use in the template.

You need to add the following code to the specified file.
Please create a custom block in your module.
<?php
namespace vendor\Magento\Block;
class CustomAttr extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function productAttr($productId)
    {
        $product = $this->product->load($productId);
        return $product;
    }
}

After creating the block, add the following code to your phtml file where you want to display the cost price on the frontend.
<?php 
    $customAttr = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor\Magento\Block\CustomAttr');
    $product = $customAttr->productAttr($_product->getId());
    echo $product->getData('cost');
    ?>


Excellent, thank you for that, worked a treat.

To display the cost price attribute in Magento 2 on the frontend in a more standard and optimized way, you can follow the steps outlined below. This method leverages dependency injection and proper Magento practices to ensure that you can easily retrieve and display custom attributes like cost price.
Step 1: Create a Custom Module

Create the Module Structure:
First, create a new module if you haven't already. For this example, let’s use Vendor/CostPrice.
Directory structure:
app/code/Vendor/CostPrice/


Create registration.php:
Create a file named registration.php in app/code/Vendor/CostPrice/:
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_CostPrice',
    __DIR__
);


Create module.xml:
Create etc/module.xml in app/code/Vendor/CostPrice/etc/:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_CostPrice" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>



Step 2: Create the Block

Create the Block Class:
Create the following file Block/CostPrice.php in your module:
<?php
namespace Vendor\CostPrice\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class CostPrice extends Template
{
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(ProductFactory $productFactory, Template\Context $context)
    {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCostPrice($productId)
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        return $product->getData('cost'); // Replace 'cost' with the actual attribute code
    }
}



Step 3: Create Layout XML

Add Layout Update:
Create a layout file to add your block to a specific page, for example, product view. Create view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
            <block class="Vendor\CostPrice\Block\CostPrice" name="cost.price" template="Vendor_CostPrice::cost_price.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>



Step 4: Create the Template File

Create Template File:
Create a template file named cost_price.phtml in view/frontend/templates/:
<?php
/** @var \Vendor\CostPrice\Block\CostPrice $block */
$productId = $block->getProduct()->getId();
$costPrice = $block->getCostPrice($productId);
?>

<?php if ($costPrice): ?>
    <div class="cost-price">
        <span><?= __('Cost Price: ') . $block->escapeHtml($costPrice); ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>



Step 5: Enable and Test the Module

Enable the Module:
After creating all the necessary files, enable the module and clear the cache:
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_CostPrice
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush



Step 6: Check the Frontend

Test on the Frontend:
Go to the product view page on your Magento store and check if the cost price is displayed.

Summary of the Approach

Dependency Injection: The block uses the ProductFactory to load the product, which is a best practice in Magento 2.
Separation of Concerns: The block handles the business logic of fetching the cost price, while the template is responsible for displaying it.
Modularity: This approach is modular, allowing you to easily adjust or extend functionality without modifying core files.

By following this structure, you maintain a clean, standard Magento development practice that adheres to the framework's best practices. If you have any further questions or need additional modifications, feel free to ask!
